# Getting exception while getting value of a field using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I need help in getting value of a field using reflection. There is a class (SocketTest.class) which has server socket implementation, socket functionality is working fine. I'm trying to get hold of a socket field of this class and I intend to call its getInputStream() method to accept inputs. Following code is giving me `IllegalArgumentException` -- `Can not set java.net.Socket field com.test.SocketTest.socket to java.lang.Class`

```
Field socketField = SocketTest.class.getDeclaredField("socket");
socketField.setAccessible(true);
Class<?> socketTest = "SocketTest".getClass();
Socket socket = (Socket)socketField.get(socketTest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `"SocketTest".getClass()` will invoke `getClass()` on the `String` instance `"SocketTest"`, which will return the `Class` representing the class `String`, in other words, is equivalent to the expression `String.class`.

Then, it’s not clear why you are passing the `Class` object to the `get` method of the `Field`. The `get` method is supposed to read the field and since this is a field declared in the class `SocketTest`, it requires an instance of `SocketTest`, not a `Class` instance, neither `SocketTest.class` nor `String.class`. If, however, the field is `static`, you don’t need to pass anything at all, you can just use `socketField.get(null)`.

Generally, you should rethink your design. If the class `SocketTest` encapsulates a `Socket` instance, it’s up to `SocketTest` to hand out an `InputStream`, if desired and *if* this is not considered to defeat the encapsulation, otherwise, you should not try to counteract this design decision using Reflection.

Comment: Thank you Holger. I understand that in this case, I'd need to pass an instance of SocketTest as a parameter to get method. As SocketTest.class will not return an instance, then is there any way to get an existing instance (considering no changes can be done in SocketTest class).

Comment: There is no such “search for an existing instance” feature. It’s not even clear why you assume, that there is an existing instance at all. What about creating an instance?

Comment: At runtime, SocketTest would create a socket connection on a specific port. So I was thinking that, in order to get an input stream of that socket, I would need existing instance of SocketTest. With a new instance, I'd get new socket connection (not where user would be connected).

Comment: That `SocketTest` that creates a socket connection on a specific port doesn’t come out of nowhere. There has to be an initiator, in other words, someone creates the instance. Perhaps, the need for these Reflection stuff disappears once you start using the software like it is *intended* to be used…